# How can I ensure my get query won't be affect by a long running update in COSMOS db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a set of updates to my container that are taking 10s+ (I will eventually bump up my RU and improve this time hopefully).

My problem is that I found that if I ran a GET during the 10s+ update, my retrieved set would include some updated records, and some yet-to-be-updated records.

How can I ensure that my GET doesn't retrieve a set of half updated data?

A few lines of thought:

- run the query 2x and compare e_tag across all results and ensure that no updates are happening (ie e_tag hasn't changed for any record), but this feel like a very big (RU expensive) hack.
- ensure my updates run as a single transaction (how is this done in COSMOS?, via a SPROC?) and lock out any GETS (but COSMOS doesn't do locks, right?)

Is there a better solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What consistency level are you using? Have you looked at the various consistency models? You might have to change which one you're using, to deal with this appropriately.

Comment: I could be wrong @DavidMakogon but the consistency levels are there to deal with consistency of containers across zones/regions, and that is not the issue I'm dealing with. What also might solve this is to (somehow, if possible?) batch up my writes/update into a single transaction (because I think my Promise.all will have n number of transactions where n is the number of updates/writes I'm doing)

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a look at *Session* consistency, for example, where you would be guaranteed consistency if using a single writer session. Aside from that: there's not much detail to go on, in your question; I suggest editing to give specific examples of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the writes (createDocument / replaceDocument - interestingly I could not get upsertDocument to work) into stored procedures, which was great for performance (3x as fast),

However, firing a "GET" during these stored-procedure run updates would still result in semi-updated datasets

So I also moved the "GET" into a stored-procedure, and Bingo! the stored-proc "GET" will now return the data from before an update started if an update is in process

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs):

Stored procedures and triggers are always executed on the primary replica of an Azure Cosmos container. This feature ensures that reads from stored procedures offer strong consistency